# What is the impact of enabling the critical update 'Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema'?

Tags: apex, critical-update

What is the impact of activating the critical update 'Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema' in a Salesforce instance? Do we have a list of things that we need to verify to activate this critical update?

Understand the critical update from [What does "Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema" actually do?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243905/what-does-enable-improved-caching-of-org-schema-actually-do/243927#243927) question. But it would be great if we have a list of items that we need to test before activating this critical update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema" actually do?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243905/what-does-enable-improved-caching-of-org-schema-actually-do)

Comment: General UAT testing of your org should be mostly sufficient. If you are looking for a specific area to test - Please test all apex code that uses sobject describe and all its flavors (GlobalDescribe, SObjectType, SObjectField) in all the different API versions of code you have.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_apex_enable_improved_schema_caching.htm),you do not need to test anything before activating this critical update since it will just fix the known bugs and behavior of your org’s schema remains unchanged.

Thank you!